# unix fdisk: get a device string knowing its system

Tags: linux, unix, mount, fdisk

I'm attaching an NTFS disk to RHEL.

To mount it, I need to know the partition name, which I will later use in the `mount` command.

I need to get a string with a `Device` name, knowing what `System` its belongs to.

```
fdisk -l
```

This command returns:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 15.0 GB, 15032385536 bytes, 29360128 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xdf77eb64

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1             128    29358079    14678976   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sda: 31.5 GB, 31457280000 bytes, 61440000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000c46d3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048    61439999    30206976   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdc: 1862 MB, 1862270976 bytes, 3637248 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf9fa7844

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1             128     3635199     1817536    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

I would love to get a string `/dev/sdc1`, because its system is `HPFS/NTFS/exFAT`

How can I get a `Device` string, knowing that it should be formatted as `HPFS/NTFS/exFAT`?

Comment: A bit unclear what you mean by "Device boot string" - is it UUID you are after? You perhaps could gain additional insight by running `lsblk` and `blkid`. What you are referring to seems to be simply device ids `/dev/sda` is the first disk detected and `sda1` bit refers to it's first partition. `sdb` is second and so on.

Comment: But if you are only after getting the string /dev/sdc1 because it is on the line containing NTFS you could simply do this: `fdisk -l | grep NTFS | cut -f 1 -d " "`

Comment: @r0berts I would love to get a "/dev/sdc1" string. I am not sure which name it will have when I do it next time, it might be "/dev/sdc2" or something else. The main this for me is to get a name, which corresponds to "NTFS" system

Comment: Have a look at `/dev/disk/by-label/`, /dev/disk/by-partlabel/` etc., and use these e.g. in `/etc/fstab`. They don't change between boots etc., and you should always use one of these instead of the `/dev/sd*` names (which can change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you want to extract the string from output of the command. Use the UNIX beloved chaining of small, simple commands in this fashion:

`fdisk -l | grep NTFS | cut -f 1 -d " "`

`fdisk` outputs the usual info - as you know. `|` is pipe symbol which means to give output to the next command, not the screen. `grep` then extracts just the line(s) containing NTFS and `cut` extracts the first field of the line(s), the column delimiter being whitespace in this case.